# Check If A PyGame Mixer Channel Is Playing A Sound

Tags: if-statement, audio, pygame, mixer

I am looking for a way to see if a `pygame.mixer.Channel` is currently playing a sound. So for example do something only after the sound played in a specific channel has finished. Here is my current code to just play the sound:

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.pre_init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()

pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(pygame.mixer.Sound('coolsound.wav'), maxtime=2000)
```

I was thinking an if statement something like this:

```
if pygame.mixer.Channel(0) = playing a sound:
    print("playing a sound")
else:
    print("not playing")
```

Obviously this wouldn't work, just to give you an idea of what I am looking for. 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Here we don't mark our questions as SOLVED. If you have an answer to the question, then post the answer in the answer question. Currently, the community will treat this as an unanswered (unsolved) question, as it doesn't have any answers.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Writing an answer right now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my answer. Using get_busy() I am able to check wether a channel is playing a sound or not, it returns `True` or `False`. Here was my final code:

```
if pygame.mixer.Channel(0).get_busy() == True:
    print("playing a sound")
else:
    print("not playing")
```

Here is a link to the documentation for more information:  https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.get_busy